# How do you access the <from> fields in a Rails mail message object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I have a message object, `@mail` and I'd like to test that the "from" name includes a string:

```
@mail.from.should include @author.name
```

however, `@mail.from` is simply an array of the addresses the mail is to be sent to, there's no mention of what label the addresses should be given.

How can I access the "from" label so that I can test it includes the author's name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [email-spec](https://github.com/bmabey/email-spec) gem for this.
Some test example from my app

```
  include EmailSpec::Helpers
  include EmailSpec::Matchers

  describe "admin details" do
    before { @admin = Factory :admin }
    subject { Mailer.admin_profile_details @admin }
    it { should deliver_to @admin.email }
    it { should have_subject 'Your account' }
    it { should have_body_text /email/i }
  end
```

Answer (score 2):

If you open up the email-spec gem, you can see it's actually checking the value of

```
@actual_sender = (email.header[:from].addrs || []).first
```

So if you'd like to do without an additional gem dependency, you can test against `header[:from].to_s` or something like that.

I had the same problem, gave up, wrote a detailed question here on stackoverflow, and found this question among "Similar questions". Funny how that works…

Comment: Be aware that header[:from] will convert a Base64 encoded header. If you build a Mail::Address and set "Motörhead" as the display_name (label), this will be Base64-encoded in the header. You won't see that when calling header[:from] though. I little gotcha that bit me today.